# How can I make a CSS Wrapper adjust height automatically?

Tags: css

I've been looking around for a while today and can't find a question that answers my specific problem.

I am designing my website and the content is in the center placed inside a div, which is the wrapper. My problem is that even though the height is set at 100%, if I add to much content, the wrapper does no stretch with the content, so the text ends up being placed outside the wrapper; it is still centered with it.

How can I fix this? The CSS I have is:

```
#wrapper {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
width: 800px;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: -400px;
background-color: #F7F7F7;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
#wrapper{height:100%;}
```

to

```
#wrapper{height:auto;}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P3huF/2/)

Comment: Wow I can't believe how simple that was. *facepalm*.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take off the Height Property, if you need to have a minimum height of 100% before the wrapper div begins to enlarge as respective to its content. so it will be:

```
#wrapper{
    min-height: 100%
}
```

not:

```
#wrapper{
    height:100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}
```